# Finding the values of 9 variables given 4 expressions and a constraint on the values of the variables

Tags: systems-of-equations

Let's say I have $9$ variables $(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i)$ and I know they are all different and they all have values between $1$ and $9$ included. Basically these variables will each have a different value between 1 and 9.

So:

$$a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i \in [1, 9]$$

$$a \neq b \neq c \neq d \neq e \neq f \neq g \neq h \neq i$$

I also know that:

$$a + b + c + d + e = 22$$

$$a + b + f + g + h = 22$$

$$d + e + g + h + i = 22$$

How do I determine the values of $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i$?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to notice is that there is likely to be a lot of solutions since given any solution we can interchange various pairs of letters and keep the same sums.

The letters $c,f,i$ are special in that they all occur in only one equation and can all be interchanged with each other.

The sums of five numbers adding to $22$ and containing a $9$ are
$$1,2,3,7,9$$
$$1,2,4,6,9$$
$$1,3,4,5,9$$
Any one of these  solutions has three elements in common with any other. This is not the case for your equations and so the $9$ can only be in one of the equations i.e. $9$ must be one of $c,f,i$.

Similarly, $8$ must also be one of $c,f,i$ and then $7$ also is one of $c,f,i$. Without loss of generality we can suppose $$c=9,f=8,i=7. $$

The equations are now easy to solve. For example:

$abcdefghi$ are respectively $249168357$.

**Number of solutions**

There are $3!$ possibilities for $c,f,i$. For each of these possibilities $a+b,d+e,g+h$ are then determined as $6,7,8$ in a particular order. These can be split as either $1+5,3+4,2+6$ or $2+4,1+6,3+5$. The total number of solutions is therefore $$3!\times2\times2^3=96.$$

Comment: Very good observations.

Comment: Thanks @Jean Marie. I've amended the answer to include the total number of solutions.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have also completely transformed my answer...

Comment: @Jean Marie Underneath your eqn 7 you have $8$ possibilities but shouldn't that be $6$?

Comment: You are perfectly right ! Thank you very much for pointing my error !

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\begin{cases}A&:=&a+b\\ B&:=&d+e\\ C&:=&g+h\end{cases}\tag{*}$$

giving for the initial system:

$\begin{cases}A+B+c&=&22\\ A+C+f&=&22\\B+C+i&=&22\end{cases}\tag{1}$

Besides, knowing that the sum of integers from $1$ to $9$ is $45$, the complementary system of the initial system is:

$\begin{cases}C+f+i&=&23\\ B+c+i&=&23\\A+c+f&=&23\end{cases}\tag{2}$

Let $s=c+f+i$ and $S=A+B+C$, we get by adding the equations in (1) and in (2):

$\begin{cases}2S+s&=&23\\S+2s&=&69\end{cases}\tag{3}$

a linear system whose solution is

$$s=c+f+i=24 \ \text{and} \ \ S=A+B+C=21\tag{4}$$

The first relationship in (4) is especially interesting because it means that:

$$\{c,f,i\}=\{7,8,9\}\tag{5}$$

implying that

$$\{a,b,d,e,g,h\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\tag{6}$$

Now, an exhaustive search can be obtained by writing (2) under the form:

$\begin{cases}C&=&23-f-i\\ B&=&23-c-i\\A&=&23-c-f\end{cases}\tag{7}$

for the $3!=6$ different combinations:

$$(c,f,i)=(7,8,9), \ \ (7,9,8), ... (9,8,7)$$

and checking each time whether the values of the triple $(A,B,C)$ are compatible with constraints (*) and (6).

Remark: in fact, an exhaustive search is rapidly done with the two solutions :

$$\begin{cases}A&=&2+4\\ B&=&1+6\\C&=&3+5\end{cases} \ \ \text{or} \ \ \begin{cases}A&=&1+5\\ B&=&3+4\\C&=&2+6\end{cases}\tag{8}$$

and their permutations.

This gives a total number of $96$ solutions in agreement with the result found by @S. Dolan (to whom I am indebted for having found a flaw in my computations).

Edit : Here is the list of the $96=2 \times 6 \times 8 $ solutions (ranked by lexicographic order, see below), the examination of which helps to understanding the declination of the 2 families of solutions (see (8)) with a tree structure with $6 \times 8$ branches. Indeed, there are $6$ ways to interchange the positions of $c,f,i$ ; and $8$ ways to arrange a solution, for given $A$ or $B$ or $C$, due to resp. exchanges:

$$a \leftrightarrow b, \ \ d \leftrightarrow e, \ \  g \leftrightarrow h.$$

$$\begin{array}{1}
   158269347\\
   158269437\\
   158629347\\
   158629437\\
   159348267\\
   159348627\\
   159438267\\
   159438627\\
   167359248\\
   167359428\\
   167539248\\
   167539428\\
   169247358\\
   169247538\\
   169427358\\
   169427538\\
   248359167\\
   248359617\\
   248539167\\
   248539617\\
   249168357\\
   249168537\\
   249618357\\
   249618537\\
   267348159\\
   267348519\\
   267438159\\
   267438519\\
   268157349\\
   268157439\\
   268517349\\
   268517439\\
   347269158\\
   347269518\\
   347629158\\
   347629518\\
   349157268\\
   349157628\\
   349517268\\
   349517628\\
   357168249\\
   357168429\\
   357618249\\
   357618429\\
   358247169\\
   358247619\\
   358427169\\
   358427619\\
   428359167\\
   428359617\\
   428539167\\
   428539617\\
   429168357\\
   429168537\\
   429618357\\
   429618537\\
   437269158\\
   437269518\\
   437629158\\
   437629518\\
   439157268\\
   439157628\\
   439517268\\
   439517628\\
   518269347\\
   518269437\\
   518629347\\
   518629437\\
   519348267\\
   519348627\\
   519438267\\
   519438627\\
   537168249\\
   537168429\\
   537618249\\
   537618429\\
   538247169\\
   538247619\\
   538427169\\
   538427619\\
   617359248\\
   617359428\\
   617539248\\
   617539428\\
   619247358\\
   619247538\\
   619427358\\
   619427538\\
   627348159\\
   627348519\\
   627438159\\
   627438519\\
   628157349\\
   628157439\\
   628517349\\
   628517439
\end{array}$$

Comment: See my "edit"...

Comment: One of your numbers seems to be wrong. Find it ! (joke for sure). One more nice solution.

Comment: I've just realised how easily the crucial $7,8,9$ result can be obtained. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Adding all the equations gives $$2a+2b+c+2d+2e+f+2g+2h+i=66$$
Since twice the sum of all the letters is  $90$ we have $c+f+i=24$ and therefore $c,f,i$ are $7,8,9$ in some order.

Now use either of the earlier answers!